# Joining two different Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can any one help me find out characterid, firstname, lastname of a killer in Harry potter Schema.

Given a table `Character (characterid, firstname, lastname, genderid)` and another table `Killedby (characterid, killerid, espisode, year)`. The Table Character includes information about all characters and in Killedby, the characterid is about the character that was killed.

Comment: which table stores killer firstname ,lastname info

Comment: The table Character stores information about every character including killers ..

Answer (score 1):

> help me find out characterid, firstname, lastname of a killer in Harry potter Schema

Since  a character can be killed only once,i suppose there will be no duplicates,a simple join would suffice.I would recommend reading [TSQL 2012 by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tsqlfund2012/) further

```
select 
ch.characterid, firstname, lastname
from
dbo.charcter ch
join
dbo.killedby kl
on 
ch.characterid=kl.killerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Character.characterid, firstname, lastname
from Character, killedby
where killedby.killerid=Character.characterid
```

The query is straightforward and self-explanatory, but in case of doubt comment indicating your problem.